# Google Api Drive Creating File with Different Domains

Tags: google-drive-api

I had a domain www.xxx.**com** and have changed to www.xxx.**co**.

I've already added this new domain on console.developers.google and authorize Google Works "third parts" to access drive.

But every time I create a file through the google API drive with my app it creates on my root count that i logged in and not on the folders of my antique domain.

Is it a problem of permission right? How can I solve this?

Comment: antique domain? What actually is happening? And what do you actually want to do?

Comment: basically when i try to create a folder (via api) through the new domain   (setting parents) it creates on my root directory folder and the created file is an unrecognized file titled "untitled".... and when i create a folder (via api)  through the old domain it creates on the right way

Comment: can you show code on how you're doing it?

Comment: i ident my code and it works... was not a domain problem

Comment: oh, so you've resolved this?